# External looping of the variable

Tags: php, javascript

How could I best loop the data through a variable that's nested inside a 'while' loop but it's called outside of it ? Like in this example:

PHP:

```
 $fr_q2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['user']."'   
 ORDER BY id DESC");
 while ($rowsPicFr2 = mysqli_fetch_array($fr_q2)) {

 $friends_q2[] = $rowsPicFr2['added_friend'];
 $frn[] = $rowsPicFr2['added_friend'];
 $frn2 = $rowsPicFr2['added_friend'];
 }

 $rowscheck = mysqli_num_rows($fr_q2);
 for ($i=0; $i<$rowscheck; $i++)
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="remdata(<?php echo $frn[$i]; ?>)">YES</a>
```

So I need to pass $frn[$i] into a remdata() function - but the $frn[$i] needs to loop....All I get is a string of all ids from 'friend_added' in $frn[$i]....Thanks.

Comment: The PHP won't be executed after the HTML is sent to the browser. PHP will be executed on the server side and JavaScript on the client side!

Answer (score 1):

Once this HTML is sent to the browser, it won't loop anymore. It will just be HTML. So what you need to do, is either have it loop in JavaScript or simply echo each remdata():

```
<a href="#" onclick="<?php foreach($frn as $f) echo "remdata({$f});"; ?>">YES</a>
```

This solution is only really an option if you have very few elements in $frn.

Comment: Hi...I see your point in here - great solution but it echoes all ids at once ( one by one ) I forgot to mention that  I need a specific id after each <a href> click. The links are the users' pics and I need remdata() to echo proper id onclick...but now I managed to workaround this by placing another javascript function inside PHP that passes ids by value to HTML link...

Comment: Ah, now I see what you want: do you want the link to remdata() a different value every time it is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing; I think you need the loop for the HTML output

```
<?php foreach ($frn as $i => $friend_id){ ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="remdata(<?php echo $friend_id; ?>)">YES</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Based on your comment in toon81's answer, it seems like you're having a problem dealing with several loops in your output that deal with the same result set in your database query. I'm not sure. I'd suggest in the future that you try to make your question easier to follow. For instance, do we need to know it's a social networking app? Your variable names aren't inherently easy to understand; what's the difference between $frn and $frn2? Presumably that's 'friend', but I keep reading it as 'fern'. You also only provided one line of your output, but your problem seems related to it's interaction with other output. Your code is cut off -- the rowscheck loop doesn't have a definition.

That said, this is a high level suggestion of how I'd handle your work differently. Data preparation:

```
$connection = ...;
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$sql = "
    SELECT added_friend
    FROM friends
    WHERE username = '$user'
    ORDER BY id DESC
";
$response = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

$added_friends = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($response)){
    $added_friends[] = $row->added_friend;
}
```

Ouput handling:

```
// With one loop if the markup can be ouput all at once.
foreach ($added_friends as $friend){
    // Your 'friends_q2', whatever that is.
    echo "Friends_q2: $friend";

    // Your 'frn2' output, whatever that is.
    echo "Frn2: $friend";

    // Your 'frn' output.
    echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"remdata($friend)\">YES</a>";
}


// ...or multiple loops if it can't.
foreach ($added_friends as $friend){
    // Your 'friends_q2', whatever that is.
    echo "Friends_q2: $friend";
}

foreach ($added_friends as $friend){
    // Your 'frn2' output, whatever that is.
    echo "Frn2: $friend";
}

foreach ($added_friends as $friend){
    // Your 'frn' output.
    echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"remdata($friend)\">YES</a>";
}
```

In any case, you're handling the same ID three times in different lists and in different ways. I'm not at all sure why. Is this what you're asking for help with?

Comment: I changed my answer to give you advice.